# Automatically expand JTree to until height threshold is met

Tags: java, swing, jtree

I have a JTree on a JScrollPane as part of my GUI. I've set up an AncestorListener where I respond to the ancestorAdded event. In the event, I would like to automatically expand as many  *visible* nodes as possible. By *visible*, I mean that I want to expand as many nodes as possible such that the total height of the tree does not exceed the maximum height of the JScrollPane's viewport. If my viewport had 500px of visible space, I want the tree expanded until the total expanded height is less than or equal to 500px.

I've tried to achieve this a few different ways. It boils down to this: I can't seem to retrieve an updated height for the tree after programatically expanding a node. How can I recalculate the height of the tree? tree.getHeight(), for example, always returns the same value even after I expand a node. Invoking tree.invalidate() between calculations didn't help either.

Comment: confused - where/how does the table come into play?

Comment: you are mixing two diferent `JComponents JTree` (about `Nodes`) with `JTable` (about `table.getHeight()` and `invalidate()`) together in your descriptions, something gone wrong, please post the Runnable code that shows ...

Comment: Whoops. I'm actually working with a TreeTable, but for the purposes of the question everything applies to a JTree. I fixed everything in my posted question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I recalculate the height of the tree?

Maybe [`getVisibleRowCount()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getVisibleRowCount%28%29)`*`[`getRowHeight()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/JTree.html#getRowHeight%28%29) will give you the correct size.

The documentation for `getRowHeight()` states that it may return `<= 0` and leave the row height up to the renderer, which may be the case for you as you're using a `JTreeTable`.